# Native android App update without google play or without using default dialog of android os

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to implement my own custom screen to update my application with both Mandatory and Non Mandatory updates . I downloaded apk in device internal memory . then currently using Intent which shows a dialog either to install or to cancel . i don't need this dialog which can be avoid if i will not use the intent for installation . but then i need solution how to update app . in sort i must have to implement custom screens for app update my app will not be available on play store.

I tried multiple third party library but that is old enough and not supporting android 13 with kotlin
also as per my current implementation i am able to download apk and then using intent to install apk which is showing a dialog . also tried package manager but still did not find correct solution. if any one having better solution please help for same.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to achieve this, as such a functionality would be a security concern. However, you can use a concept called "Device Owner" to grant your app a sort of admin permissions without rooting it. See the following [blog post](https://medium.com/@codybrookshear/creating-an-android-device-owner-app-in-2023-b7e7b9fb3aca) for a description:

> Device Owner is an Android Enterprise feature supported by Android OS
> since version 5.0. It allows you to create an application that can
> fully manage a device.

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#afw) mentions the ability for an app that is a Device Owner to **silently install apps**. Maybe that is what you are looking for:

> Silent install and uninstall of apps by Device Owner: A Device Owner
> can now silently install and uninstall applications using the
> PackageInstaller APIs, independent of Google Play for Work. You can
> now provision devices through a Device Owner that fetches and installs
> apps without user interaction. This feature is useful for enabling
> one-touch provisioning of kiosks or other such devices without
> activating a Google account.

The steps to get a test setup working are summarized below. Please read into the [blog post](https://medium.com/@codybrookshear/creating-an-android-device-owner-app-in-2023-b7e7b9fb3aca) yourself on how to use it in production.

---

Add a receiver to the `manifest.xml` file of the app that you want to make a Device Owner:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".DeviceOwnerReceiver"
  android:description="@string/app_name"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
  android:exported="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.app.device_admin"
      android:resource="@xml/device_owner_receiver"/>
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Add the configuration file device_owner_receiver.xml that was referenced above. Here you set the privileges that the app should have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password/>
        <watch-login/>
        <reset-password/>
        <force-lock/>
        <wipe-data/>
        <expire-password/>
        <encrypted-storage/>
        <disable-camera/>
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Define an class that declares the app as a Device Owner:

```
class DeviceOwnerReceiver : DeviceAdminReceiver() {

    @Override
    override fun onProfileProvisioningComplete(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val manager = context.getSystemService(ComponentActivity.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE) as DevicePolicyManager
        val componentName = ComponentName(context.applicationContext, DeviceOwnerReceiver::class.java)

        manager.setProfileName(componentName, context.getString(R.string.profile_name))

        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

---

To finally enable the Device Owner role for your application, connect your phone to the PC using adb and execute the following command:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner my.sample.app/.DeviceOwnerReceiver
```